# HuggingFace 'TFEmbeddings' object has no attribute 'word_embeddings'

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Trying to run [this TextualHeatmap example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/AndreasMadsen/python-textualheatmap/blob/master/notebooks/huggingface_bert_example.ipynb#scrollTo=IMyHY55SC24O), we encounter `'TFEmbeddings' object has no attribute 'word_embeddings'` error in the following code snippet from the HuggingFace *transformers* library. Any help is appreciated.

```
from transformers import TFDistilBertForMaskedLM, DistilBertTokenizer 
dbert_model = TFDistilBertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased') 
dbert_tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased') 
dbert_embmat = dbert_model.distilbert.embeddings.word_embeddings
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @cronoik It's 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Try to use '.weight' instead of '.word_embeddings' as per hugging face latest implementation. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the version of transformers will work.

```
pip install transformers==3.1.0
```